# Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

The error appeared when exporting data in a datagrid view to an Excel sheet:

> error (Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD)))

on this line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
```

How do I fix this problem?

My full code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    // Creating Excel Application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;

    // Creating new WorkBook within Excel application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

    // Creating new Excel sheet in workbook
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

    // See the Excel sheet behind the program
    //Funny
    app.Visible = true;

    // Get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
    // Store its reference to worksheet
    try
    {
        // Fixed:(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
        worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

        // Changing the name of active sheet
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from Ketoan";

        // Storing header part in Excel
        for (int i = 1; i < DGData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = DGData.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        // Storing each row and column value to Excel sheet
        for (int i = 0; i < DGData.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DGData.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = DGData.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        // Save the application
        string fileName = String.Empty;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileExcel = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileExcel.Filter = "Excel files |*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileExcel.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = saveFileExcel.FileName;

            //Fixed-old code: 11 para->add 1:Type.Missing
            workbook.SaveAs(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        else
            return;

        // Exit from the application
        //app.Quit();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        app.Quit();
        workbook = null;
        app = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please format this so that it is legible.

Comment: You already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179196/error-when-export-datagrid-view-to-excel-sheet/5179312#5179312

Comment: Its because of regional language of OS other than "en-US". I already answered this in hyperneed.com. To see the answer visit below link : http://www.hyperneed.com/ShowSearchAnswers.aspx?searchstring=&category=Programming&questionid=5afa16f5-653a-4f2e-afcb-c83dce5bc4e4

Answer (score 9):

Consider:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
```

Delete this line or move to under the line that closes the Excel application.

It works for me.

Answer (score 6):

The real reason is the regional settings configured for the user that launches the thread. It is documented as a bug.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369

Comment: This is the real reason and the solution is to just set the culture to the Excel culture before opening and reverting to old culture after closing.

Answer (score 5):

Your code works fine on Office 2007 + VS 2010. What versions are you using? Mayby you have choosen wrong version of interop refernece: Office 2007 = 12.0.0.0, Office 2010 = 14.0.0.0

You can look at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369 it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it:
Look at this:
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel doesn't work on 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263130/microsoft-office-interop-excel-not-work-on-64-bit/8274888#8274888)

Answer (score 1):

You should type this line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
```

Do this after you close your Excel application; before adding WorkBook you should not use this line.