# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel doesn't work on 64 bit

Tags: asp.net, interop, hresult, comobject

I've encountered a problem when developing on MS Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Ed.
Developing ASP.NET C# on Windows7 64 bit OS.

I'm trying to open an Excel document, but it gives me `Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))`

I did configured the build to all processors (Any CPU, x64, x86) but it doesn't work. I searched the answer on the internet but couldn't find out how to handle it.

The weird thing is the same code worked on the same system when I developed on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express! how come? isn't it the same dll working behind?

Do I need to change that COM dll so it'll work on x64 system?

Please help me, what can I do?

My code is:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
__Log("Openning " + excelFileName);
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure this willl solve your problem, but if you have a 32-bit COM DLL, you probably need to use an x86 build of your project even if you are running on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea @Andrew. If it's 32bit Excel, 64bit .net won't want to work with it. Build it as x86 and it should work.

Comment: Already tried that.. but the same happened, I dont understand why this problem is not occure in Visual C# and only in Web developer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging the internet I found out that there is a bug in Microsoft Interop with COM objects (at least with my case which is MS Excel 2010).

The bug is that .NET checks that your thread (C# or VB code) localization is suitable to MS Excel localization you installed earlier, and if not it tells that the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` library is old or invalid.

Your thread localization is derived from your computer regional settings (from the control panel --> regional and language)

Then there are two options to solve this problem:

1. To change your thread localization (by code)
2. Install language pack for your Office

The first solution goes like this:

```
using System.Threading;     // For setting the Localization of the thread to fit
using System.Globalization; // the of the MS Excel localization, because of the MS bug

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
excelFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(excelPath, "Ziperty Buy Model for Web 11_11_2011.xlsm");
```

Hope it helps :)
gr8 day

Comment: ...for more info, the KB entry that corresponds: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369

Comment: @Otiel : The KB seems to say this bug applies to VS 2005 and Excel 2007 (and older versions). The description seems to match but it might be an unrelated bug.